# Is there any query to know which parameter is used in the stored procedure at the time of execution in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

The below query is used for getting last execution time and date but can I get the **parameter used** in it while execution in SQL Server?

```
SELECT 
    o.name,
    s.last_execution_time,
    s.type_desc,
    s.execution_count
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats s
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE 
    DB_NAME(s.database_ID) = 'XYZ' --Database Name
    AND o.name LIKE ('%ABC%') --Object Name
```

[image]

Comment: I don't follow. You've only specified two system `VIEW` names. Why do you believe there's a parameter involved?

Comment: Because to execute that stored procedure we have to provide a parameter. So, I wanted to know which parameter was used while execution and for that I need a query which I am not able to find. @jw11432

Comment: I don't see a stored procedure name. But whatever the param is, you can just add it to the SELECT statement. `SELECT column, @parameter FROM table...`

Comment: [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4992/how-to-find-compiled-parameter-values-for-sql-server-cached-plans/) is for sql server, not sure about azure but might be of help.

Comment: as it seems you are interested in the last execution of the proc you can enable LAST_QUERY_PLAN_STATS option so that plan is available and then look at the runtime param values in that (probably)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @HoneyBadger's comment, and this will help for you:

The article shows [how to find compiled parameter values for SQL Server cached plans](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4992/how-to-find-compiled-parameter-values-for-sql-server-cached-plans/).